# adding bullhorn handlebars, what about shifter and rear derailleur?

Tags: shifter, derailleur-rear, bullhorn

I am changing to bullhorn handlebars and I'm having some difficulty figuring out **what sort of derailleur and shifter** I should get. I would like to use a 9 speed bar end shifter as I currently have a SRAM X5 1x9 drivetrain running 11-34 - 9 speed cassette with a 42T chainring.

I will be mostly commuting and I don't want 'bottom of the barrel' as far as price but I also don't want 'top of the line' professional components either.

Comment: It's not clear if you are looking for a shifter unit, or a rear derailleur or both.

Comment: I'd like a 9 speed thumb shifter and I'm willing to change the derailleur if need be.  I currently have a SRAM X5 9 speed shifter but I have no allegiance to SRAM.

Comment: In the question you say "bar end shifter" and in your comment you say "thumb shifter". Those are two different things. This a pretty broad question and is basically asking for a product recommendation. There are so many possible options out there that we can't really give a definitive answer. I would say, find the shifter you want then pick a derailleur that's compatible.

Comment: ok you are correct and thank you. I meant thumb shifter. I'm realizing now that what I want is the use the Paul thumbies to turn a down tube shifter into a 'thumb shifter'. But I appreciate your final suggestion. It's helped me  a lot! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I did not find any SRAM 9-speed compatible bar end shifters, so as you say the easiest path forward is to swap out the derailleur as well.

Microshift makes a range of Shimano MTB compatible bar-end shifters in 8, 9, 10 and 11 speeds.

If you want to stick with 9 speed you need an Alivio or below (Acera, Altus) derailleur. Alivio is definitely not 'scraping the bottom of the barrel' and is perhaps a step up from SRAM X5. An Alivio 9 speed derailleur will work with your cassette.

If you want to upgrade to 10 speed then Deore and SLX derailleurs are options. You will obviously need to get a 10 speed cassette and chain as well.

Comment: You can also use a jtek shiftmate too

Answer (score 2):

We don't do product rec here, but I will note that SRAM rear derailleurs are compatible across road and mountain groups for 9 speed, as are Shimano.

So, if you have a Shimano rear derailleur, buy another Shimano shifter and keep the existing derailleur (or Shimano compatible, e.g. from Microshift). If you have a SRAM rear derailleur, replace Shimano with SRAM in the last sentence and ignore the parenthesis.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this forum so what's 'product rec'? And yes I did search for a SRAM (or any other for that matter) bar end shifter  but was unable to find any. That's the reason for this post. If there is a bar end shifter that would work with the SRAM X5 then great. Please direct me if so. I haven't been able to find any in my research which is why I was thinking I would have to change the derailleur to Shimano in order to get a bar end shifter that would work.

Comment: *Product recommendations*